# confused about the mean of negative binomial distribution

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Let X be a random variable of the negative binomial distribution with parameters $r$ and $p$, 
$$P(X = n)~=~{n-1\choose r-1} p^r(1-p)^{n-r} .$$
The textbook says the mean is ${r(1-p)\over p}$, which confuses me because I always  consider the negative binomial distribution random variable $X$ as the sum of $r$ independent  geometric distributed random variable $\tau$, 
$$P(\tau = n)~=~p(1-p)^{n-1}.$$
Then by linearity of expectation, we get the mean of $X$ should be ${r\over p}$,since the mean of $\tau$ is ${1\over p}$. Can anyone helps me figure it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different conventions for the geometric distribution. One counts the number of trials, has support $\{ 1,2,\dots \}$, and has mean $1/p$. The other counts the number of failures, has support $\{ 0,1,\dots \}$, and has mean $(1-p)/p$.

Summing iid copies of these gives two different kinds of negative binomial distributions. There is also a variant of the negative binomial distribution which counts successes rather than failures, so that $p$ and $1-p$ get switched around. You simply have to be aware of the convention being used in a given context.

Comment: Hi Ian, the convention for the negative binomial distribution is about the total number of trials to get the r success? If it is about the number of trials, then I think the mean of $X$ should be $r\over p$, is that right? Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @QingSUN If you are counting the total number of trials until the $r$th success then yes the mean should be $r/p$.

Answer (score 0):

The computation of the mean of a negative binomial distribution is usually
done by means of a 'differentiation trick'.

First, let's look at a geometric random variable $X$ that counts the
number of trials up to the appearance of the first Success in a sequence
of Bernoulli trials. $P(X = k) = q^{k-1}p,$ for $k = 1, 2, \dots .,$ where
$0 \le p = P(\text{Success}) \le 1$ and $q = 1-p.$

To find the mean:

$$E(X) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty kq^{k-1}p = p\sum_{k=1}^\infty kp^{k-1}.$$

The series is summed as follows:

$$\frac{d}{dq}\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty q^{k}\right) = \sum_k kq^{k-1},$$

where differentiation within the series is justifiable.
Then

$$E(X) = p\sum_k kq^{k-1} = p\frac{d}{dq}\left(\sum_k q^k\right)
= p\frac{d}{dq}\left(\frac{q}{1-q}\right),$$
upon summing the geomeric series. Finally,

$$E(X) = p\left(\frac{1}{(1-q)^2}\right) = \frac 1p.$$

Then a negative binomial random variable $Y,$ for the waiting
time until $r$ successes is the sum of $r$ geometric random variable
for the waiting time until one success. Hence $E(Y) = rE(X) = \frac rp.$

In computational situations, it may be possible to sum many
terms of the series for $E(X)$ to get a useful approximation.
For example, if $X$ is a geometric random variable with $p = 1/3,$
then $E(X) = 3.$ Consider the following computation in R, in which 100 terms of the series are summed:

```
p = 1/3; q = 1-p;  k = 0:100
pdf = q^(k-1)*p
sum(k*pdf)
[1] 3
```

The implementation of the geometric distribution in R counts
the number of failures before the first success, taking values
$0, 1, 2, \dots.$ Thus the sample mean of a million randomly
generated independent geometric observations with $p = 1/3$
gives a value $E(X) = 3$ correct to within a 95% margin of error
of about $\pm 0.005.$

```
set.seed(2019)
x = rgeom(10^6, 1/3)
mean(x + 1)
[1] 3.000108
2*sd(x)/sqrt(10^6)
[1] 0.004911733
```

*Note:* If you know about [moment generating functions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/427538/what-is-the-moment-generating-function-of-px-x-alpha-thetax/427553#427553), you can find
that the MGF of $Y$ is $m_y(t) = \left[\frac{pe^t}{1-qe^6}\right]^r.$ Then to get $E(X)$ take the first derivative of $m_Y(t)$ (with respect to $t)$ and
evaluate it at $t=0.$

*Ref:* Except for notation, the derivation above of $E(X)$ via differentiation is similar to that of Wackerly, Mendenhall, Scheaffer: *Math. stat. w/ appl, 6e*, p112, Duxbury, 2002.